# Ios with UIImagePickerController cause SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, sigabrt

I am very new to iOS development, and as I follow the instruction from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW10), although it already told me to add a privacy - photo library usage to my properties item inside the info.plist to solve the sigabrt error, and I already did add that, it still show the sigabrt error. I am currently running the code from a simulator. Is it because I run it in simulator instead of real device?

Here is the viewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

//MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    nameTextField.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK: UITextFieldDelegte
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
    mealNameLabel.text = textField.text
}

//MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
    guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK: Actions
@IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
}

@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Hide the keyboard
    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}
```

Comment: ok,,can you please show your code? It will be better for answer or comment. By the way if you are accessing camera, app would get crash.

Comment: okay, I've edited my question, I don't know if it will access the camera since I set the source type to .photoLibrary.

Comment: Are you sure your @IBOutlet properties are connected?

Comment: I think so, because I dragged it from the storyboard

Comment: Please check again your code & Linking. I have tried your code with copy paste and it's fine. You are facing some another issue.  For camera, I would suggest create a global instance of UIIMagePickerController i.e    


    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePickerController.delegate = self  

 in ViewDidLoad

Comment: I still can't find whats wrong, I have make sure everything is connected, and can see the circle icon to left of each IBOutlet or IBAction, but still the same error of Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key selectImageFromPhotoLibrary.'